# java - Error casting Set.toArray() as Object[]

Tags: java, object, casting, set

I am attempting to grab a random element from a Set of custom Objects (Space) and receiving an error in doing so.

```
Space[][][][] spaces = new Space[dim][dim][dim][dim];
Set<Space> spaceSet = new HashSet<Space>();

for(int i=0; i<dim; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<dim; j++)
        for(int k=0; k<dim; k++)
            for(int l=0; l<dim; l++) {
                spaces[i][j][k][l] = new Space(i,j,k,l);
                spaceSet.add(spaces[i][j][k][l]);
            }
...
Space s = null;
...

s = (Space[])spaceSet.toArray()[rand.nextInt(spaceSet.size())];  //This line throws the error
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LSpace;
    at Maze.generatePath(Maze.java:45)
    at Maze4D.main(Maze4D.java:15)
```

Answer (score 1):

An array of Objects cannot be cast to an array of Foos. You will need to iterate over the array and cast each member individually. (Better yet, properly use generics / polymorphism and don't cast.)

Answer (score 1):

Because [as the docs point out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28%29), `toArray()` returns an `Object[]`

You need  to use the [*other* `toArray(T[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) if you want the type inferred:

```
s = spaceSet.toArray(new Space[0])[rand.nextInt(spaceSet.size())];
```

(The supplied array in this case is just being used for the type inference; `toArray()` is returning a new `Space[]` of the appropriate size)

Answer (score 0):

When trying to work with Random size/space. Its always a better idea to use a map instead of arrays going down several levels. Here is an example of the something similar where you could set/get values with minimal boiler plate code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SmartPropertyReader {
    private SmartPropertyReader parent;

    protected final String PRESERVE_MAP = "PRESERVE_MAP";
    protected final String PRESERVE_LIST = "PRESERVE_LIST";
    private String preserveType;

    protected Map<String, SmartPropertyReader> map = new HashMap<String, SmartPropertyReader>();
    protected Object value;
    protected List<SmartPropertyReader> list = new ArrayList<SmartPropertyReader>();

    public SmartPropertyReader(){
        this.parent = null;
    }

    public SmartPropertyReader(SmartPropertyReader parent, String preserveType) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.preserveType = preserveType;
    }


    public SmartPropertyReader get(String key) {
        SmartPropertyReader subProp = map.get(key);
        if(subProp == null){
            subProp = new SmartPropertyReader(this, PRESERVE_MAP);
            map.put(key, subProp) ;
        }
        return subProp;
    }


    public void setValue(Object passedValue) {
        list.clear();
        map.clear();

        if(passedValue instanceof SmartPropertyReader){
            this.map = ((SmartPropertyReader) passedValue).map;
            this.list = ((SmartPropertyReader) passedValue).list;
        }else{
            this.value = passedValue;
        }

        SmartPropertyReader currPropertyReader = this;
        while(currPropertyReader != null){
            String preserveType = currPropertyReader.preserveType;
            currPropertyReader = currPropertyReader.parent;
            if(PRESERVE_MAP.equals(preserveType)){
                currPropertyReader.clearList();
                currPropertyReader.clearValue();
            }else if(PRESERVE_LIST.equals(preserveType)){
                currPropertyReader.clearValue();
                currPropertyReader.clearMap();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void clearList(){
        list.clear();
    }

    protected void clearMap(){
        map.clear();
    }

    protected void clearValue(){
        this.value = null;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        if(this.value == null){
            SmartPropertyReader currPropertyReader = parent;
            while(currPropertyReader != null){
                String preserveType = currPropertyReader.preserveType;
                if(PRESERVE_MAP.equals(preserveType)){
                    currPropertyReader.clearMap();
                }else if(PRESERVE_LIST.equals(preserveType)){
                    currPropertyReader.clearList();
                }
                currPropertyReader = currPropertyReader.parent;
            }
        }
        return this.value;
    }


    public SmartPropertyReader get(int index) {
        while(list.size() <= index ){
            list.add(null);
        }
        SmartPropertyReader subProp = list.get(index);
        if(subProp == null){
            subProp = new SmartPropertyReader(this, PRESERVE_LIST);
        }

        list.set(index, subProp);
        return subProp;
    }


    public String toString(){
        String retString = "";
        if(value != null){
            retString = value.toString();
            if(value instanceof String){
                retString = "\"" + retString + "\"";
            }
        }

        if(list.size() > 0){
            String listStr = listString();
            if(!listStr.equals(""))
                retString = "[" + listString() + "]";
        }

        if(map.size() > 0){
            String mapStr = mapString();
            if(!mapStr.equals(""))
                retString = "{" +mapString() + "}";
        }

        return retString;
    }


    private String listString (){
        String str = "";
        boolean first = true;
        for(SmartPropertyReader rblt: list){
            if(rblt != null ){
                String subStr = rblt.toString();
                if(!subStr.equals("")){
                    if(!first)
                        str += ", ";
                    str += subStr;
                    first = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    private String mapString(){
        String str ="";
        boolean first = true;
        for(String key: map.keySet()){
            SmartPropertyReader rblt = map.get(key);
            if(rblt != null){
                String subStr = rblt.toString();
                if(!subStr.equals("")){
                    if(!first)
                        str += ", ";
                    str += "\""+key + "\": " + subStr;
                    first = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SmartPropertyReader propertyReader = new SmartPropertyReader();
        propertyReader.get("Test").get("2nd key").get("A number value").setValue(10);
        propertyReader.get("Test").get("a key").get(1).get(2).setValue(100);
        propertyReader.get("Test").get("a key").get(1).get(3).setValue(100.345);
        propertyReader.get("Test").get("a key").get(2).get("Nice").setValue("Nice value in the stack");

        propertyReader.get("Test").get("a key").get(5).setValue("This would work too");
        System.out.println(propertyReader.toString());
        System.out.println(propertyReader.get("Test").get("2nd key").get("A number value").getValue());
        System.out.println(propertyReader.get("Test").get("a key").get(1).get(2).getValue());
        System.out.println(propertyReader.get("Test").get("a key").get(1).get(3).getValue());
        System.out.println(propertyReader.get("Test").get("a key").get(2).get("Nice").getValue());
        System.out.println(propertyReader.get("Test").get("a key").get(5).getValue());
    }

}
```